# Character tables of isomorphic groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, characters

Let us consider two groups $G$ and $G'$ which are isomorphic to each other. Since isomorphic groups can be considered as same upto isomorphism, is the character table same for both groups?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes. But the converse is not true.

Comment: More precisely they are the same up to permuting the rows and columns of the tables. I have been told that testing computationally whether two large character tables are the same in this sense is not as easy as you might imagine.

Comment: @DerekHolt Interesting point. Certainly determining whether two matrices are the same up to permuting rows and columns is difficult -- if the matrices are $0/1$-matrices this is just the graph isomorphism problem for bipartite graphs. For groups one usually imagines there is a lot more structure in the character table that you can use, but there is probably a large family of $p$-groups that are really annoying (even class 2 maybe?).

Comment: @SeanEberhard I don't know the details. I suspect that the groups in question were subgroups of very large simple groups, and the computations were feasible but annoyingly slow when there were lots of characters with the same degrees and classes with the same sizes. This was a decade or two ago, so I expect the computations are much faster now.

Answer (score 0):

As Derek Holt said in the comments, both tables are equal up to rows and columns permutations. To prove the assert, consider an isomorphism $\sigma:G'\to G$ and an irreducible character $\chi\in\text{Irr}(G)$. If $\mathcal X$ is a representation of $G$ affording $\chi$ then $\mathcal X\circ\sigma$ a representation of $G'$ (since it is a composition of homomorphisms) affording $\chi\circ\sigma$. Now, since $\sigma$ is a bijection it holds
$$[\chi,\chi]=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|\chi(g)|^2=\frac{1}{|G'|}\sum_{g'\in G'}|\chi(\sigma(g'))|^2=[\chi\circ\sigma,\chi\circ\sigma].$$
Hence, $\overline{\sigma}:\text{Irr}(G)\to\text{Irr}(G')$ defined as $\overline{\sigma}(\chi)=\chi\circ\sigma$ is well-defined, and it is a bijection since its inverse is the function $\psi:\text{Irr}(G')\to\text{Irr}(G)$ such that $\psi(\chi')=\chi'\circ\sigma^{-1}$ for each $\chi'\in\text{Irr}(G')$. The result follows from the fact that group isomorphisms preserve conjugacy classes.